# newView(), bindView() scrolling with checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, scroll, cursor

I want to make contact picker and downloaded a sample app from developer.android.com - and now I am trying to add checkbox for the contact list.

However I found that when I try scolling then checkbox set checked randomly.

After a weeks search, I learned that this is because of recycling the view and found many articles solving problems with getView().

However, I cannot use the answers and examples shown for getView(), because my code - originally from developer.android.com - is useing newView(), bindView().

I also found some answers suggesting that adding a new column into the database for boolean numbers about whether it is checked, but I am getting data from Caontacts so I cannot modify the database. So, I cannot use this solution.

Would you please help me?  Here is my code - almost the same with example from developer.android.com.

```
    public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    final String photoUri = cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_DATA);

    final String displayName = cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.DISPLAY_NAME);
    final int startIndex = indexOfSearchQuery(displayName);
        if (startIndex == -1) {
            holder.text1.setText(displayName);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearchTerm)) {
                holder.text2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {

        final SpannableString highlightedName = new SpannableString(displayName);


        holder.text2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        final Uri contactUri = Contacts.getLookupUri(
                cursor.getLong(ContactsQuery.ID),
                cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.LOOKUP_KEY));

        final CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        final  int position = cursor.getPosition();

        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
             //// SHOULD I TO SOMETHING HERE???
            }
        });
```

Comment: what i do is make the ``OnCheckedChangeListener`` as a class member, each time get the view, first set ``null`` to the listner and reset the checked state, and then reset the member listener and the state, then do all other stuff.